# What is "primary" in hyper-v console and what is the default password?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-manager, ubuntu-multipass

I opened up my Hyper-V Manager console, and I noticed a VM running with the name "primary", which points to Ubuntu server-cloud muitipassd etc (see screenshots).

When I try to connect to it, it shows me a prompt to login:

Q1) How did this "primary" get there? I would never name my VM's with the name primary

Q2) What is the default password to login?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged as WSL2?  Inspection of the configuration file might be helpful

Comment: Tagged as WSL2 because I have a hunch this was a linux subsystem installed by WSL. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking

Comment: So what is contained within the VMs configuration file?  Do you have a WSL2 instance running?  Is the up time of your WSL instance 16 days?

Comment: those questions should be asked to whom every set up the "primary' VM.  No VMs are default or installed by Hyper-V.  That VM was setup by someone in your organization.  Creating a new WSL instance requires a password during setup, there isn't a "default" login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out the "primary" VM was not setup manually by anyone.

It was setup when I ran Ubuntu multipass for Windows, found here
https://multipass.run/

To use a linux instance, open a normal (Windows) command prompt and enter

> multipass shell primary

That will be my linux shell (very similar to WSL2).